# Recommended approach for combining Aurelia build revisions and unit testing

Tags: aurelia

When creating a new Aurelia project using the CLI (`au new`) with unit testing and build revisions enabled. I get a warning message that karma cannot find the `vendor-bundle.js` and `app-bundle.js`.

> 14 03 2017 08:54:27.260:WARN [watcher]: Pattern
>   "C:/Temp/AureliaTest/scripts/vendor-bundle.js" does not
>   match any file.
>
> 14 03 2017 08:54:27.266:WARN [watcher]: Pattern
>   "C:/Temp/AureliaTest/scripts/app-bundle.js" does not match
>   any file.

I understand that the bundles name should include a hash like `vendor-bundle-{hash}.js`, but what is the recommended approach to let karma know what the name of the bundle is?

I updated to the newest Aurelia CLI (0.26.1) and created a new project with the following steps:

- App name : Test
- Custom setup
- Typescript
- Default template
- CSS processor: Sass
- Unit testing: Yes
- Default code editor: VS code
- Create the project: Yes
- Install dependencies: Yes

I enabled build revisions in the `aurelia.json`: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/8

```
"options": {
  "minify": "stage & prod",
  "sourcemaps": "dev & stage",
  "rev": true
}
```

Aftwerwards I ran the build (`au build`) and ran the unit tests (`au test`)

This results in the following code sample: https://github.com/jimmyvdberg/aurelia-revisions-and-unit-tests

Comment: Just tested this with a new typescript project created from aurelia-cli. Works fine for me with revision numbers. What version of CLI are you using? Mapping should happen in `karma.conf.js`.

Comment: I updated the CLI version but I still get the warning messages. I updated the post with some extra info about `karma.conf.js`

Comment: `karma.conf.js` content looks fine so far. Can you provide access to a repository showing this issue? Or write down the steps you took in the CLI creation process?

Comment: @MarcScheib I updated the question again with the installation steps and placed the result on my GitHub account.

Comment: I would say it is a bug. au build produce the hash version of the files and au test is looking for the standard names. Open an issue for aurelia-cli?

Comment: Ah, I did a mistake in reproduction. I executed the tests without revisions first. Then, again with revisions. But the old files without revision were not cleaned up. In fact, it's not working for me either.

Comment: I opened an issue on GitHub. I will update/remove the question once I'm sure that it is a bug or when there is a solution. https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/554

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it for me by changing the karma.conf.js and delete the created bundle files on each build.

karma.conf.js changes:

```
const scriptsFolder = './scripts/';
const fs = require('fs');

let appSrc = fs.readdirSync(scriptsFolder).filter(fn => (fn.startsWith('app-bundle') || fn.startsWith('vendor-bundle')) && !fn.endsWith('.map')).map(fn => path.join(output, fn));

console.log('appSrc', appSrc);

// configTarget from aurelia.json is vendor-bundle.js
// let entryIndex = appSrc.indexOf(path.join(output, project.build.loader.configTarget));
let entryIndex = appSrc.indexOf(appSrc.filter(f => f.includes('vendor-bundle'))[0]);
```

build.ts changes

```
import * as clean from './clean';

....

export default gulp.series(
  clean.deleteScripts, // added this one
  readProjectConfiguration,
  gulp.parallel(transpile, processMarkup, processCSS, copyFiles),
  writeBundles
);
```

clean.ts // my own clean up stuff

```
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import * as del from 'del';

export default gulp.series(
  deleteScripts
);

export function deleteScripts() {
  return del([
    './scripts/**/*.*',
    '!./scripts/modernizr-custom.js',
    '!./scripts/oidc-client.min.js',
    ], {dryRun: false}).then(paths => {
    console.log('Deleting following Files and folders:\n', paths.join('\n'));
  });
}
```

It would be nice to have something like this in the CLI. It is very confusing to run test for different environments and the CLI is not working like expected. Aurelia is copying the environment file on build tasks and you can have written different behaviours on environments in your application. All this should of course be testabl